# Access base class variable from child static function

Tags: c++, static

```
class A
{
   public:
    void init();
    void method1();
    void method2();

   private:
    bool _var1 = false;
    bool _var2 = false;
};

class B : public A
{
   public:
    static void method3();
};

B::method3()
{
    _var1 = false
}
```

If I call method3, I get the expected error "invalid use of member 'A::_var1' in static member function".

I have many classes which need to be static (have static functions), and many of the common variables and properties I need to inherit from a base class for code tidiness. What's the best solution for this problem?

Point me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: What a real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a lot of 'B' classes, and they all have static functions which use common state properties, for example, I have 3 classes: "wifi", "ethernet" and "ppp" and they all use common properties such as "isConnected", "ip" and "linkState". I create a base class for the common properties and access them from the static functions of the child class.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], the description is so obscure. The error is pretty clear, you can't access non-static members from static member functions.

Answer (score 0):

a static function is not associated with an object hence cannot access class members.
see [reference for more details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

you may need to pass an object instance as a function argument if that static function requires to use one e.g.

```
   B::method3(B& b)
   {
        // do something with b
        if b.isConnected() ) {}
   }
   bool B::isConnected(){return _isconnected;}
```